# Can I Hide a Question In a SharePoint Survey?

Tags: 2010, survey, survey-list

Let's say I have a Survey with 3 questions:

1. What's your favorite color?
2. What's your favorite candy?
3. Please enter some comments

Now lets say, I want to hide question 3, "Please enter some comments", so that it is only visible to an administrator who comes in to respond to the survey. Essentially, I want to hide question 3 from everyone who is responding to the survey.

Is there any way to do this out of the box in SharePoint 2010?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box? No. But it can be done with SharePoint Designer and some JavaScript code.

A survey is just a SharePoint list with a custom display. SharePoint does not have field level (question in Surveys) security.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tutorial on how to do this? I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: Not that I've seen, but would not surprise me to find a blog article or forum solution for something related.